# How to ensure typeof and cast operators operate on a different load context not the default load context

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-core, f#

I'm using .NET core and trying to compare types loaded via reflection into an assembly load context (not the default load context) with a known compile-time type. However, if I use the `typeof` operator like so:

```
if(x.GetType() == typeof(KnownType))
```

The result is always false even when all the properties of the two types (including the location they were loaded from is the same), presumably because they are loaded into different load contexts... the custom context and the default context.

I can get this to work by pre-loading the known type or interface into the custom context, getting a reference to it and doing the comparison like so:

```
   if(x.GetType() == preloadedKnownType)
```

However, I have a similar situation with casts. If I do:

```
   var y = x as KnownType
```

the cast fails, presumably because they are loaded into different contexts.

Is there a way to use `typeof` and cast operators with a type loaded into a custom context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load an assembly into a different `AssemblyLoadContext` the idea is usually to isolate the types. Even if the binary is the same, the code will treat it as different. This means that the type instances are different ([see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/understanding-assemblyloadcontext#how-are-dynamic-dependencies-isolated)).

The `typeof` operator gets checked at compile time, so the type has to exist. It wouldn't suddenly match your dynamically loaded type because, as explained above, the types are different instances.

So the that your check `if(x.GetType() == typeof(KnownType))` fails is expected behavior.

---

A nice thing of the `AssemblyLoadContext` is that you can also share dependencies. If you provide a type in a library and share that assembly in both contexts you can check those types.

For example. Consider the following interface and class:

```
// Located in Library.DLL
public interface SomeInterface
{
    string SomeValue { get; }
}
```

```
// Located in Main.DLL
public class KnownType : SomeInterface
{
    public string SomeValue => $"{this.GetType().Name} ({this.GetType().GetHashCode()})";
}
```

```
// Get the types
var localType = typeof(KnownType);
var loadedType = Assembly.LoadFile(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).GetType(localType.FullName);

Console.WriteLine($"{localType} {localType.GetHashCode()}");   // PRINTS: Main.KnownType 58225482
Console.WriteLine($"{loadedType} {loadedType.GetHashCode()}"); // PRINTS: Main.KnownType 54267293
Console.WriteLine($"Comparison: {loadedType == localType}");   // PRINTS: Comparison: False

// Create instances
var localInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(localType) as SomeInterface;
var loadedInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(loadedType) as SomeInterface;

Console.WriteLine(localInstance.SomeValue);  // PRINTS: KnownType (58225482)
Console.WriteLine(loadedInstance.SomeValue); // PRINTS: KnownType (54267293)
```

In short, `Assembly.LoadFile`  will load the target assembly into a new AssemblyLoadContext isolating it from the default context. As no dependency resolver exist within this AssemblyLoadContext it will just reuse the known library assembly already loaded.

When executing this code, the hashcodes and comparison show that on runtime the type instances are different, even though its the exact same DLL. However, as they implement an interface that is within the shared assembly (`SomeInterface`), both objects can be cast to it and used.

See the guide on working with the AssemblyLoadContext [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/understanding-assemblyloadcontext). It also explains how you can share dependencies between different contexts if you have a custom `AssemblyLoadContext`.